# Can I implement an e-signature-only of a PDF provided by the calling application with Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

My use case only requires Docusign for e-signature of pre-filled PDF forms.

The PDF forms will be generated on our application side where some fields will be automatically filled (using xPressions) and the user will fill in the remaining blank fields.

The use case:

1. In our web application the user is presented with a task/action.
2. After invoking the task the user is presented with a PDF form.
3. The user fills in the blank fields of the PDF form and closes it.
4. The user is then invited to e-sign the document.
5. The web applications initiates a session with Docusign and transfers the PDF document to Docusign.
6. The web application hands control over to Docusign (in an IFrame) where the user can add a signature to the document.
7. Docusign hands control back to the web application.
8. The user task is complete.
9. The web application retrieves the e-signed document.
10. End

In this use case we don't have a need for Docusign templates or powerforms as the PDF generation solution already exists. This existing PDF generation solution is quite complex and it would not feasible or cost effective re-implement within the Docusign solution.

My question, is the above, e-signature-only, use case feasible within the docusign solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use "embedded signing" to keep the entire flow within your web app.  This is accomplished by specifying a "captive recipient" as the signer.  In addition to name and email address, you will specify a "clientUserId" for the signer.  This should be specific and unique to the actual signer, e.g. a "customer ID", employee ID, etc.  In a pinch, you can use the email address.

See (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this API [endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) to create an envelope by passing your pdf.
See [guide](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/documents) and section "Attaching documents to an envelope"